# Premiere Pro 2021 Refusing to Load My Project

Tags: video, bug

On Premiere Pro 2021 whenever I try to work on a project that has multiple layers, it refuses to load it and instead I am met with “project is pending” and it refused to load it and then crashes.

I tried importing the project into a new project and the same thing happened.

Comment: You should contact Adobe for support. I think this cannot be sovled without access to your system or many more details what exactly was done with this project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting preferences and/or plugin cache?
From [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-reset-premiere-pro-preferences-rameez-khan/):

> Press Alt (Windows) or Option (Mac OS) while launching Premiere Pro.
> You can release the Alt key or Option key when the splash screen
> appears.
>
> To reset preferences and plug-in cache at the same time, hold down
> Shift-Alt (Windows) or Shift-Option (Mac OS) while the application is
> starting. Release the Shift-Alt keys or Shift-Option keys when the
> splash screen appears.